# Why do I get syntax error when using DateAdd

Tags: dateadd

I am using the following expression in the Criteria section of an Access Query
<DateAdd("m", -3, Date() )

I have tried it with quotes and hash characters etc but every time I get
"The expression you entered contains invalid syntax"

I have aslo used the expression builder with the same results.

Any ideas.

Comment: Your parenthesis are not equal : you miss a closing ) at the end.